# Как во множество добавить двухзначное число

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

При добавлении во множества двухзначных и более чисел, они попадают туда не целиком, а по частям: например 15, как 1 и 5. Как исправить?

```
n, m = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
Anya = set()
Borya = set()
        
for i in range(n):
    Anya.update(input())
            
for i in range(m):
    Borya.update(input())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `.add`, он добавляет один элемент. `.update` итерируется по переданному аргументу, он нужен для добавления коллекций. А строка итерируется как её отдельные символы, поэтому вы наблюдаете такое поведение кода.

Но вам нужно будет взять ещё `int` от ввода иначе в множество добавится строка, а не число, это будут разные элементы.